# Printing colors in python terminal

Tags: python, terminal

I'd like to make a program that prints colors in the python terminal but I don't know how. I've heard that you can use certain escape sequences to print text in color, but I'm not sure of this. How can I print a string in a specific color using the python terminal?

Side note: I run a version of Linux.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Try the [`termcolor`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/termcolor) module.

```
from termcolor import colored

print colored('hello', 'red'), colored('world', 'green')
```

See [Print in terminal with colors using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors-using-python/293633#293633)

Also, you could use ANSI codes:

```
class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'

    def disable(self):
        self.HEADER = ''
        self.OKBLUE = ''
        self.OKGREEN = ''
        self.WARNING = ''
        self.FAIL = ''
        self.ENDC = ''

print(bcolors.WARNING + "Warning" + bcolors.ENDC)
```

Comment: for Python 3.4, `print(colored('hello', 'red'), colored(' world', 'yellow'))`