# Search word in python

Tags: python

I have text file, I am searching for specific word "Belief". I want the word to be shown in red colour if it was found.

```
searchfile = open("demo.txt", "r")
text=input("Enter search word :")
for line in searchfile:
    if text in line:
        print(line)
searchfile.close()
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Do you want to find 'Belief' or do you mean 'Believe'?

Comment: Do you mean the functionality of `grep` on Unix systems?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22886353/printing-colors-in-python-terminal

Comment: Colorama?  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama

Answer (score 0):

You can get colors as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors-using-python)

If you are not using Windows you could try `termcolor` to do something like this:

```
from termcolor import colored

text=input("Enter search word :")
with open("demo.txt", "r") as searchfile:
    for line in searchfile:
        if text in line:
            print(colored(text,'red').join(line.split(text)))
```

Example:

```
s = "123 321 123 321 123"
print(colored("321",'red').join(s.split("321")))
```

With output:
[image]

If you do use windows, you could still run the same code as above, as long as you add the following two lines at the beginning of your script:

```
from colorama import init
init()
```

Both libraries are pip-installable and lightweight.

Comment: from colorama import init

init()
s="123 321 123 321"
print(colored("321",'red').join(s.split("321")))