# Color Text Only Partially Working

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I input something like:

`print('\x1b[6;30;42m' + 'Success!' + '\x1b[0m')`

the output I get is:

[image]

With no color.

I've heard you any need to enable vt100 emulation for windows, but when I search for how to do that, I haven't seen any answers.

All answers are very appreciated!

Comment: See the answer where the termcolor module is suggested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22886353/printing-colors-in-python-terminal

Answer (score -1):

```
    printf("\033[1;42m Success! \033[0m \n");

    color as below:
    none = "\033[0m"
    black = "\033[0;30m"
    dark_gray = "\033[1;30m"
    blue = "\033[0;34m"
    light_blue = "\033[1;34m"
    green = "\033[0;32m"
    light_green -= "\033[1;32m"
    cyan = "\033[0;36m"
    light_cyan = "\033[1;36m"
    red = "\033[0;31m"
    light_red = "\033[1;31m"
    purple = "\033[0;35m"
    light_purple = "\033[1;35m"
    brown = "\033[0;33m"
    yellow = "\033[1;33m"
    light_gray = "\033[0;37m"
    white = "\033[1;37m"
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue